# Working with Excel LookUP and IF Function

Tags: excel, function, if-statement, lookup

im new with excel and my questions is ;

why excel cant accept this formula ;

=LOOKUP(H5,{1.01,1.02,1.03,1.04,1.05,1.06,1.07,1.08,1.09,1.1,1.11,1.12,1.13,1.14,1.15,1.16,1.17,1.18,1.19,1.20,1.21,1.22,1.23,1.24,1.25,1.26,1.27,1.29,1.30,1.31,1.32,1.33,1.34,1.35,1.36,1.37,1.38,1.39,1.40,1.41,1.42,1.43,1.44,1.45,1.46,1.47,1.48,1.49,1.50,1.51,1.52,1.53,1.54,1.55,1.56,1.57,1.58,1.59,1.60,1.61,1.62,1.63,1.64,1.65,1.66,1.67,1.68,1.69,1.70,1.71,1.72,1.73,1.74,1.75,1.76,1.77,1.78,1.79,1.80,1.81,1.82,1.83,1.84,1.85,1.86,1.87,1.88,1.89,1.90,1.91,1.92,1.93,1.94,1.95,1.96,1.97,1.98,1.99,2.00,2.01,2.02,2.03,2.04,2.05,2.06,2.07,2.08,2.09,2.10,2.11,2.12,2.13,2.14,2.15,2.16,2.17,2.18,2.19,2.20,2.21,2.22,2.23,2.24,2.25,2.26,2.27,2.28,2.29,2.30,2.31,2.32,2.33,2.34,2.35,2.36,2.37,2.38,2.39,2.40,2.41,2.42,2.43,2.44,2.45,2.46,2.47,2.48,2.49,2.50,2.51,2.52,2.53,2.54,2.55,2.56,2.57,2.58,2.59,2.60,2.61,2.62,2.63,2.64,2.65,2.66,2.67,2.68,2.69,2.70,2.71,2.72,2.73,2.74,2.75,2.76,2.77,2.78,2.79,2.80,2.81,2.82,2.83,2.84,2.85,2.86,2.87,2.88,2.89,2.90,2.91,2.92,2.93,2.94,2.95,2.96,2.97,2.98,2.99,3.00},{"1.21","1.22","1.23","1.24","1.25","1.26","1.27","1.28","1.29","1.30","1.31","1.32","1.33","1.34","1.35","1.36","1.37","1.38","1.39","1.40","1.41","1.42","1.43","1.44","1.45","1.46","1.47","1.48","1.49","1.50","1.51","1.52","1.53","1.54","1.55","1.56","1.57","1.58","1.59","1.60","1.61","1.62","1.63","1.64","1.65","1.66","1.67","1.68","1.69","1.70","1.71","1.72","1.73","1.74","1.75","1.76","1.77","1.78","1.79","1.80","1.81","1.82","1.83","1.84","1.85","1.86","1.87","1.88","1.89","1.90","1.91","1.92","1.93","1.94","1.95","1.96","1.97","1.98","1.99","2.00","2.01","2.02","2.03","2.04","2.05","2.06","2.07","2.08","2.09","2.10","2.11","2.12","2.13","2.14","2.15","2.16","2.17","2.18","2.19","2.20","2.21","2.22","2.23","2.24","2.25","2.26","2.27","2.28","2.29","2.30","2.31","2.32","2.33","2.34","2.35","2.36","2.37","2.38","2.39","2.40","2.41","2.42","2.43","2.44","2.45","2.46","2.47","2.48","2.49","2.50","2.51","2.52","2.53","2.54","2.55","2.56","2.57","2.58","2.59","2.60","2.61","2.62","2.63","2.64","2.65","2.66","2.67","2.68","2.69","2.70","2.71","2.72,"2.73","2.74","2.75","2.76","2.77","2.78","2.79","2.80","2.81","2.82","2.83","2.84","2.85","2.86","2.87","2.88","2.89","2.90","2.90","2.91","2.92,2.93","2.94","2.95","2.96","2.97","2.98","2.99","3.00","3.01","3.02","3.03","3.04","3.05","3.06","3.07","3.08","3.09","3.10","3.11","3.12","3.13","3.14","3.15","3.16","3.17","3.18","3.19","3.20"})

Or this ,

=IF(E2=1.01,"1.21",IF(E2=1.02,"1.22",IF(E2=1.03,"1.23",IF(E2=1.04,"1.24",IF(E2=1.05,"1.25",IF(E2=1.06,"1.26",IF(E2=1.07,"1.27",IF(E2=1.08,"1.28",IF(E2=1.09,"1.29",0))))))))

where is the problem here? PLEASE someone help me

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? This is almost certainly not a good way to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

The latter one will not work because the opening and closing parentheses do not pair off (though Excel should have offered to adjust for that automatically).

Answer (score 0):

It appears that what you want to do is:
If the value of E2 is in the range 1.01 to 3.00, then add 0.2 to the value of E2, otherwise return zero.
If that's correct - this formula should work:

=IF(3.00>=E2>=1.01,E2+0.2,0))

Answer (score 0):

For your lookup just go to a new worksheet type all your values there and do the look up(you need to type your your reference like E2: 1.01 , REQ: 1.01 ) 
req being what you want

```
  =vlookup(ref,array,column to match, False)
```

You could do the same for your if condition also